# (PHP composer) Is there a mean to load global installed packages into local composer.json

Tags: php, json, composer-php

On my computer Ubuntu, I use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) for :

- local-installing packages into my project
- global-installing librairies for my bash usage (phpunit, phpcs, phpmd for example)

In my project, I have a myproject/composer.json file with

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "lib-curl": ">=7",
    "ext-curl": ">=7"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": ">=6"
}
```

In my global ~/.composer/composer.json I already have

```
"require": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": ">=6"
}
```

Is there a mean to specify in my project that the phpunit is already installed on global and having  :

- myproject/vendor/bin/phpunit as symnlink toward ~/.composer/vendor/bin/phpunit
- myproject/vendor/autoload.php including the classes of ~/.composer/vendor/phpunit ?

Comment: There's no way to do this that I know of unless maybe you add a custom script to set up symlinks and add a custom autoloader.  But I would recommend against this because there's good reason each project gets its own composer setup.  It lets you mix library versions on you system in a way that global dependencies don't.

Comment: What’s the purpose?

Comment: The purpose : I have a lot of projects on my computer. I use PhpStorm and configure codeception & phpunit in it for each project. I would like to configure only one time the path of codecept and phpunit in PhpStorm for all projects. My colleagues have same projects than me. The package codeception/c3 must be into each project, but the package codecept/codecept can be global.